# session timeout asp.net and authentication

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

I have some sites with authentication process, that works properly. But in new developed site, timeout is too short. it is correct in my local but after publish, it redirects to login page after less than five min.
I check

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="200" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

and this

```
<sessionState timeout="200"/>
```

I read some similar questions and follow them, change timeout value, change slidingExpiration value and ...  but i could not solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was from my web hosting company. They changed my site Settings and problem solved.